# Cypress-Audit file name depending on test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, lighthouse

I am using the Cypress-Audit plugin for cypress to generate Lighthouse Reports.

I am following the documentation and it is all working fine except one thing.

https://mfrachet.github.io/cypress-audit/guides/lighthouse/reports.html#generating-html-reports

```
    lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
      console.log("---- Writing lighthouse report to disk ----");

      fs.writeFile("lighthouse.html", lighthouseReport.report, (error: any) => {
        error ? console.log(error) : console.log("Report created successfully");
      });
    }),
```

This generates my file correctly, but if I run cy.lighthouse twice in one test for 2 different pages, the second test will overwrite the results of the first test.

I want to have a small E2E test that goes through 3-4 pages and gives me the results for each of the page. But the problem is that it always writes the results to the same file and It overrides the previous results...